# Protocol to Hang up from browser on any softphone

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

I am using self developed CTI system and trying to integrate with softphone.

Currently I have integrated with AGEphone (https://www.ageet.com/home-en) however, the quality of the sound is pretty bad. The only reason why I am using AGEphone is it has protocol to hang up the call.

So I was wondering if there are any other softphone which has protocols to hang up from browser feature.

Doesn't matter if the software is free or paid.
Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is any common "protocol" but simple way to control softphone is to use windows' protocol handler mechanism (like callto: links - they are passed to application as command line). Links normally contain phone numbers but can also pass commands. For specific software recommendations use http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ rather.

Answer (score 0):

You can hangup any call using asterisk AMI or ARI interface. No need special software for that.